# Extract text from HTML after a specific string in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a 20k html files and I am looking to extract all text relating to 'Principal Risks'.

Where Risks text is available there is normally a heading called 'Principal Risks' followed by paragraph(s) of text that describe the risks.

The problem is that the 'Risks' heading can be contained in a h, div or td etc tag and the paragraphs after he heading can also be contained within a diversity of structures, multiple paragraphs etc

I am wondering is there some way to search the entirety of the html for the string 'Principal Risks' and then extract the following x words that follow this string, even though they are contained within a diversity of tags thereafter?

Thank you

I have experimented with Rvest but I am not getting anywhere so far

Comment: You can probably use `html_text2()` then some string parsing. However, string parsing is completely dependent on the _exact_ structure of the text, so if you need more specific help, we need a concrete example (perhaps a link to one of the htmls)?

Answer (score 1):

After you've got your text (using `{rvest}`'s `html_text2()`, for example), you can use `{stringr}` and regex to extract the text that follows after a specific string, using a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

First, let's create some example text that contains the "Principal Risks" string somewhere inside it (in this case, in the first line):

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Principal Risks consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, 
eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
```

Then, we use `{stringr}` to extract text that happens after the key string, until the next punctuation character (".").

```
stringr::str_extract(text, "(?<=Principal Risks).*\\.")
```

...where `(?<=string` instructs regex to find a string and return what's after it, `.*` means "anything after the string" and the last part `\\.` is a escaped dot character (because a dot is a special character in regex that means "any character", we have to escape it using `\\` so that regex knows that we are talking about a literal dot). In other words: find everything after the key string up until a dot character.

The result is, as expected, the text following the string until a dot is reached:

```
[1] " consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
```

Now, if your text contains the key string many times, you simply need to change `str_exract` to `str_extract_all` to get a vector of results:

```
text2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Principal Risks consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim Principal Risks ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem Principal Risks accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, 
eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto  Principal Risks beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."

stringr::str_extract_all(text2, "(?<=Principal Risks).*\\.")
```

Which returns this:

```
[[1]]
[1] " consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."    
[2] " ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
[3] " beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
```

Comment: Hi Bastian, I'm new to Statexchange and it wont allow me click the arrow to the left of your answer (above the zero) as I do not have enough reputation points. Is there another way I might be able to mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I don't know, but don't worry!